# Simple way to modal text from a datafield in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="message" HeaderText="message" SortExpression="message" />
```

I am using ASP.NET for the first time and trying to get a message box option for my gridview. What I currently have works and shows all the info, however the message takes up the whole screen.

I was hoping to just have a button and we could click it to open.

Comment: What kin of message you wan to open did you mean JavaScript alert or what ?

Comment: The message im trying to display comes from the Datafield="message" and its just a long string of text

Answer (score 0):

Well, if that data colum is already displayed, then I can't say it makes a whole lot of sense to pop up a dialog that displays what we have already on the form.

However, this task, this goal, this need, this want to create a row click event? Well, that need and want is a PURE GOLD!!

In other words, the task of having some kind of button on a row, and then dealing with that button row click is VERY much a bread and butter question. In other words, a button click on a row has a million, if not a billion use cases.

So, there are two approaches that tend to work for such cases (a row click). In one case, we might need to run some code behind. Maybe jump to a another page, maybe pop up a edit dialog to edit that one row, maybe approve some project or whatever. So, this super common case of wanting to run code behind based on the row click is as noted, a common and useful goal.

However, in your case, since the information is already existing on the page, then we can with relative ease use 100% client side code, and not even bother with some code behind for this task and goal.

so, next up?

We need some kind of dialog pop up system. And the built in "alert()" for the browsers are REALLY terrible looking, don't have much position and size options, and even worse yet will halt calling JavaScript code on the page.

So, you need to find/adopt/use/search for some kind of dialog system. (one that is popular, easy to install, and one that you can adopt and use for the next 10-15 years).

Since near everyone has and uses jQuery? (and even older asp.net templates install jQuery)?

Then I suggest jQuery.UI "dialogs" - it plays nice with jQuery, and that choice has many features that you need and want for a typical web site anyway.

So, say we have this grid view:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CssClass="table table-hover" Width="50%"
            DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="Hotel Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Descripiton" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn"
                            OnClientClick="mypop(this);return false;" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <div id="mypoparea">
        </div>
```

Note the button we dropped into the grid.

Our code behind to fill out the GV:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();

    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }            
    }
```

And now we see/have this:

[image]

So, since the data is "already" in the grid, then we can do this 100% client side, and do so with this code:

```
<script>
        function mypop(btn) {
            myTR = $(btn).closest("tr")
            myTD = myTR.find("td")

            myDialog = $("#mypoparea")
            myDialog.text(myTD[3].innerText)

            myDialog.dialog({
                title: "Description Text",
                modal: true,
                sizable: true,
                width: '380',
                closeText: "",
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog('close')
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
```

And now we see this:

[image]

so, you are free to set the size of this dialog pop box.

However, we can use server side code for the row click, and VERY OFTEN we need to run code behind, and that code behind has to deal with the ONE row of information for the given button click.

So:

Lets wire up a server side button click, and get the row information.

Our button becomes this:

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn"
                            onclick="cmdView_Click"
                         />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

And now code behind becomes this:

And keep in mind code behind can get/grab/pull fields and columns and data that does NOT exist in the gv row we display.

so, code behind to get that row and information looks like this:

```
    protected void cmdView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        // get row index
        Debug.Print("Row index click = " + gRow.RowIndex);
        // get database PK id
        int pkID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];
        Debug.Print("Database PK id = " + pkID);

        // get description text
        string strDesc = gRow.Cells[3].Text;
        mypoparea.InnerText = strDesc;

        // now call our pop dialog or whatever


    }
```